# Is a log. colorbar possible?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

Is it possible to get a logarthmic colorbar?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.2,colorbar]
\addplot[
scatter,mark=square*,only marks,
point meta=\thisrow{myvalue}
]
table {
x y  myvalue
0.5  1 0.25
0.2  2 3
0.7  3 0.75
0.35  4 0.125
0.65  5 2
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Solution?->

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{lg10}{1}{ \pgfmathparse{ln(#1)/ln(10)}}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.2,colorbar, colorbar style={yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{10^\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult}]

\addplot[
scatter,mark=square*,only marks,
point meta=\thisrow{myvalue}
]
table {
x y  myvalue
0.5  100 554
0.2  2000 3546546
0.7  3745 0.755
0.35  74 0.125
0.65  775 2555
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

This is the solution? is this logaritmic? Looks linear

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!  Yes it is: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/267144/124842, https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23750/124842.

Comment: i dont understand the solution... can somebody explain this to me with my example? thank you in advance

Comment: Add this to your preamble: `\pgfmathdeclarefunction{lg10}{1}{    \pgfmathparse{ln(#1)/ln(10)}}` and then set your `axis` optional argument to `[enlargelimits=0.2,colorbar,
    colorbar style={yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{10^\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult}]`

Comment: \documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{lg10}{1}{ \pgfmathparse{ln(#1)/ln(10)}}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=0.2,colorbar, colorbar style={yticklabel=\pgfmathparse{10^\tick}\pgfmathprintnumber\pgfmathresult}]

\addplot[
scatter,mark=square*,only marks,
point meta=\thisrow{myvalue}
]
table {
x y  myvalue
0.5  100 554
0.2  2000 3546546
0.7  3745 0.755
0.35  74 0.125
0.65  775 2555
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}

Comment: @steven can you look at my solution? for me it looks linear

Comment: When I compile your solution, I get a logarithmic colorbar, as you had asked for, with a scale of (1,10,100,1000)x10^6.  The axes are linear, but you did not ask for log axes, but a log colorbar.